# Vue3 Multiple Instances of Composition API Data Store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Simplifying a real-life situation...

Let's say I have a webapp with two columns. The same component used in both columns. The functionality uses data storage and functions created in a separate composition api js file, made available to the component by importing and then provide/inject. Works great.

But is there a way to write the js file with the composition api once, and then create multiple instances when it's imported to the Vue app? That way a separate instance can be sent to each component and they won't share the same data object. I know if you import the same file with multiple names...

```
import instanceone from "path";
import instancetwo from "path";
```

...they'll both share the same objects because it's importing the same file as two names, not two instances of the file.

Is there any way to achieve something like this? I'm interested in any setup that would achieve the end goal (not needing two copies of the file to achieve two independent usages). I took a flyer and thought maybe creating a single file that exports objects and functions, then two files that each import the appropriate pieces of that single file, and then let Vue import those two files might work...but nope, not so much.

Obviously there are plenty of other ways to do this, but I want to explore this possibility first. Preferably without making use of Vuex.

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it's possible. The module should export a function that creates new objects. It's hard to determine a suitable solution without seeing the module's code. Can you update the question to include that?

Answer (score 0):

the following is one of the way to achieve this

```js
/* composable_module.js */

import { ref, computed } from 'vue';

export const shared_var_1 = ref(0);
export const shared_var_2 = ref(0);

export function composable_variables() {
 // will return separate instance of variables for each call
 const var1 = ref(0);
 const comp_var1 = computed(() => var1.value + shared_var_1.value);
 // comp_var1 updates value when either var1 or shared_var_1 value gets updated
 return { var1, comp_var1 };
}
```

usage as following

```js
/* component_1.vue */
import { shared_var_1, shared_var_2, composable_variables } from 'composable_module.js';


/* other things needed for component or any file */
setup() {
 const { var1, comp_var1 } = composable_variables();
 /*
 Do what you want to do with
 shared_var_1, shared_var_2, var1, comp_var1
 */
 // return whatever you wanted to use in template
 return { shared_var_1, shared_var_2, var1, comp_var1 }
}
```

Here `shared_var_1`, `shared_var_2` will act as vuex store values
and `var1`, `comp_var1` will be separate for each function call
so can be used in multiple components as separate variable sharing common functionality but not value.

Answer (score 0):

Within your 'path' composable you could define two states, then call the relevant state with something like:

```
const { getItem1, getItem2, setItem1, setItem2 } = (whichInstance) ? instanceOne : instanceTwo
```

You just need to define your whichInstance condition to determine which instance you want.

Your composable could be something like:

```
const stateOne = reactive({
    item1: true,
    item2: 1
})

const stateTwo = reactive({
    item1: false,
    item2: 2
})

export function instanceOne() {
    let stateRef = toRefs(stateOne)

    /* Getters */
    const getItem1 = () => {
        return stateRef.item1
    }
    const getItem2 = () => {
        return stateRef.item2
    }

    /* Mutations */
    const setItem1 = (value) => {
        stateRef.item1.value = value
    }
    const setItem2 = (value) => {
        stateRef.item2.value = value
    }

    return {
        state: toRefs(stateOne),
        getItem1,
        getItem2,
        setItem1,
        setItem2
    }
}


export function instanceTwo() {
    let stateRef = toRefs(stateTwo)

    /* Getters */
    const getItem1 = () => {
        return stateRef.item1
    }
    const getItem2 = () => {
        return stateRef.item2
    }

    /* Mutations */
    const setItem1 = (value) => {
        stateRef.item1.value = value
    }
    const setItem2 = (value) => {
        stateRef.item2.value = value
    }

    return {
        state: toRefs(stateTwo),
        getItem1,
        getItem2,
        setItem1,
        setItem2
    }
}
})
```